# Can not add row to jTable from jComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've `jComboBox` and `jTable`
I write following code on 
    `jComboBoxKeyTyped` to add row from    `jComboBox` selected item.

---

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable);
        jComboBox.setEditable(true);
        jComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        jComboBox.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jComboBoxKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 236, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void jComboBoxKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
        String name = (String) jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if ((jComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(name)) && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            df.addRow(new Object[]{(jComboBox.getSelectedItem())});
        }
    }                                  
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable;
}
```

---

If user typed desired name and hit enter must add it to jtable but it doesn't adding a row.

> I consider that event is cause,
>   Usually we first select Item from jComboBox and then coding on
>   event for example jButton.
>   So here I want event on jComboBox that consider selected item to be added to jTable.

So on which event I must write code or another way to approach?

Comment: So .. does that code as seen above, replicate the problem for anyone that runs it? I removed the down vote given this is short and 'ready to run', but when running it, I .. realised I have little idea what the actual problem is. BTW - since the combo is not editable, I suspect it behaves a little differently to what you expect, and should probably retain the enter key event for collapsing the open list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `JComboBox` does not support key listeners (`addKeyListener`). But I was able to add rows to the table by using `addActionListener()`. But we need to filter events using `actionCommand` of the event.

When user select an item from the drop down, an `ActionEvent` is fired with `actionCommand="comboBoxChanged"`. When user press the Enter key, `actionCommand="comboBoxEdited"`.

```
jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("comboBoxEdited")) {
      DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
      tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{(jComboBox.getSelectedItem())});
    }
  }
});
```